# Joining SQL date range to existing script

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble creating a date range in my SQL script.

I have created a date range table ('dt' table) that runs OK as an independent script but, when added to the following script it only shows dates where the trunc(rl.daudate) = dt.dateval. I need the dt.dateval to show even if there is no match to trunc(rl.duedate)

```
select dt.dateval, rl.reservation_no, gr.title, gr.catnr, rl.duedate, rl.work_center_no, rl.tec_criteria, rl.qty
from gps_reservation gr, GPS_RESERVATION_LOAD rl,
(select x.dateval from 
    (select (trunc(sysdate+90) - rownum) -1 dateval from dual 
    connect by rownum < (1*90) ) x ) dt
where rl.reservation_no = gr.reservation_no
and rl.plant = 'W'
and gr.active_flag = 'Y'
and gr.cap_flag = 'Y'
and trunc(rl.duedate) = dt.dateval
```

I would usually use an (+) join, i.e.

```
and trunc(rl.duedate) (+) = dt.dateval
```

... but, I get an 'ORA-00936: missing expression :-936' error ?

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: stop using syntax that is antique ANSI 92 is already 22 years old, so syntax that pre-dates that has to be considered ancient. Use ANSI syntax instead of (+)

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to join without the (+) syntax. I'm self taught using existing code from old reports, I've never used anything other than(+).

Comment: OK, but you are seriously out of date; try this visual guide to joins http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Try this: trunc(rl.duedate (+)). But as @Used_By_Already already told, it is better to use ANSI syntax. Maybe this helps: http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/ansi_joins.html

Comment: 2 tips on the newer syntax. 1, don't use commas in the from clause any longer and 2, the sequence does matter you cannot join to a table that isn't already joined. That is why I have altered the table sequence in the from clause below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
       dt.dateval
     , rl.reservation_no
     , gr.title
     , gr.catnr
     , rl.duedate
     , rl.work_center_no
     , rl.tec_criteria
     , rl.qty
FROM (
     SELECT (trunc(sysdate + 90) - rownum) - 1 dateval
     FROM dual connect BY rownum < (1 * 90)
     ) dt
LEFT JOIN GPS_RESERVATION_LOAD rl ON dt.dateval = trunc(rl.duedate)
                                     AND rl.plant = 'W'
LEFT JOIN gps_reservation gr      ON rl.reservation_no = gr.reservation_no
                                     AND gr.active_flag = 'Y'
                                     AND gr.cap_flag = 'Y'
```